# Coinbase Sandbox API /accounts call - Invalid Signature with curl

Tags: bash, curl, coinbase-api

Greets,

Looks like I'm having a similar problem to others ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69556092/when-calling-coinbase-pro-sandbox-api-invalid-401-unauthorized-text-messa) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204699/coinbase-pro-api-invalid-signature)), but seem to be missing something obvious.  Trying to call Coinbase Sandbox API /accounts to get a list of accounts.  Literally the most basic call to get into this...

Following the SIGN docs at [docs.cloud.coinbase.com](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/sign-in-with-coinbase/docs/api-key-authentication)

To understand the problem, I'm using stock standard BASH script with a `curl` call:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TS=$(date +%s)
API_KEY=fbb28bed4617217f482d878770b8c9b7
PASSPHRASE="passphrase87867"
SECRET="apcep9z66jyW3koh5uHhnq0hKQ5q59EBgTtpZ/GsvN9aigrFbxMpuz+YP7xXo/ev+OBZpqmv4OpCk7OKx6qGbw=="
URL="https://api-public.sandbox.exchange.coinbase.com/accounts"
#https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/accounts \
#https://api-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com/accounts \

SIG=$(echo "${TS}GET/accounts" | hmac256 --binary $API_KEY | base64)
#SIG=$(echo "${TS}GET/accounts" | hmac256 --binary $SECRET | base64)
#also tried with PASSPHRASE & SECRET and without base64:
#SIG=$(echo "${TS}GET/accounts" | hmac256 $PASSPHRASE)
#SIG=$(echo "${TS}GET/accounts" | hmac256 $SECRET)

curl --request GET \
     --url $URL \
     --header 'Accept: application/json' \
     --header "cb-access-key: $API_KEY" \
     --header "cb-access-passphrase: $PASSPHRASE" \
     --header "cb-access-sign: $SIG" \
     --header "cb-access-timestamp: $TS"
```

#comments indicate various settings I've tried.

I just keep getting the `{"message":"invalid signature"}` error.

I'd appreciate any pointers.

/update:
This page contains a way to calculate the signature (binance, yes, I get the irony):  https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#signed-trade-user_data-and-margin-endpoint-security :

```
echo -n "symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j"
```

Thanks

Comment: I think SIG=$(echo "${TS}GET/accounts" | hmac256 $SECRET) might be correct, based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204699/coinbase-pro-api-invalid-signature, but $SECRET needs to be decoded first, resulting in raw bytes, which cannot be passed in on the command line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness sake, here's the C# solution:

```
using RestSharp;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Globalization;

string computeSignature(
        HttpMethod httpMethod,
        string secret,
        double timestamp,
        string requestUri,
        string contentBody = "")
{
    var convertedString = System.Convert.FromBase64String(secret);
    var prehash = timestamp.ToString("F0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + httpMethod.ToString().ToUpper() + requestUri + contentBody;
    return hashString(prehash, convertedString);
}

string hashString(string str, byte[] secret)
{
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
    using (var hmaccsha = new HMACSHA256(secret))
    {
        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(hmaccsha.ComputeHash(bytes));
    }
}

var timeStamp = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
var apiKey = "fbb28bed4617217f482d878770b8c9b7";
var passPhrase = "passphrase87867";
var secret = "apcep9z66jyW3koh5uHhnq0hKQ5q59EBgTtpZ/GsvN9aigrFbxMpuz+YP7xXo/ev+OBZpqmv4OpCk7OKx6qGbw==";
var URL = "https://api-public.sandbox.exchange.coinbase.com/accounts";

var client = new RestClient(URL);
var request = new RestRequest();
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("cb-access-key", apiKey);
request.AddHeader("cb-access-passphrase", passPhrase);
request.AddHeader("cb-access-sign", computeSignature(HttpMethod.Get, secret, timeStamp, "/accounts"));
request.AddHeader("cb-access-timestamp", timeStamp);
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
// ...
```